# Matlab plot a threshold line

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to add a horizontal threshold line to my graph of 0.7. But I can't seem to get it to work.

**Code**

```
figure(1)
plot(Variance);
hold on;
plot([1 frames], threshold, 'red')
```

Variance is an array to be plotted and the frames are the number of variances that are plotted. I've tried moving the `hold` and `plots` around but it doesn't seem to work either.

I know this is an easy question, but everything I've looked at online doesn't seem to work either, with regards to adding them to the same `plot()`.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the second plot to plot([1 frames], [threshold threshold], 'red') ?

Comment: That done it, I knew it was going to be something simple that I was missing. Thanks

Comment: @wakjah You should post that as an answer, so that the OP can accept it and the question be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the second plot line to

```
plot([1 frames], [threshold threshold], 'red');
```

Comment: I can't understand how this work can you explain a little?